Solidworks mass properties extraction
Are there any tools out there that will automatically extract the mass properties of each component in a solidworks assembly file and output this data in a csv file or excel file, etc. ?

Well, you can do it using SolidWorks itself. 1) add the mass propertie to each component 2) add a BOM table with a column refering to the propertie you have create 3) save the table as csv file or excel file.

I've just checked and you don't need to add the proppertie to the components. You can just 1) add a BOM table column refering to mass 2) save the table as csv file or excel file.

@solidWorking, when I insert a column to the BOM, none of the column type options give me the ability to add mass.

You're right. I've tested with an assembly with shetmetal components and sheetmetal components allways have the mass properties from the cut list properties. sorry for misleading you.

You can use this macro:
Option Explicit
Dim f As Object
Sub main()
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swConf As SldWorks.Configuration
    Dim swComp As SldWorks.Component2
    Dim fso As Object
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    If swModel Is Nothing Then MsgBox ("No Assembly"): Exit Sub
    If swModel.GetType <> swDocumentTypes_e.swDocASSEMBLY Then MsgBox ("Not an Assembly"): Exit Sub
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\AssemblyMass.CSV")
    f.WriteLine "Name,Mass(Kg)"
    Set swConf = swModel.GetActiveConfiguration
    Set swComp = swConf.GetRootComponent3(True)
    TraverseComponent swComp
    f.Close
End Sub
Sub TraverseComponent(swComp As SldWorks.Component2)
    Dim vComps As Variant
    Dim vComp As Variant
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim MyMassProp As SldWorks.MassProperty2
    vComps = swComp.GetChildren
    For Each vComp In vComps
        Set swComp = vComp
        TraverseComponent swComp
        Set swModel = swComp.GetModelDoc2
        Set MyMassProp = swModel.Extension.CreateMassProperty2
        Debug.Print swComp.Name2 & vbTab & " Mass: " & Round(MyMassProp.Mass, 3) & " Kg"
        f.WriteLine swComp.Name2 & "," & Round(MyMassProp.Mass, 3)
    Next
End Sub

